# TypeError: $value undefined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

In html file,

```
 <tr class="odd" ng-click="parseProductId(product.product_id);show = !show">
   <td>{{product.product_id}}</td>
   <td>{{product.name}}</td>
   <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{order.currency_code}} {{product.unit_price}}</td>
   <td>{{order.currency_code}} {{product.unit_discount}}</td>
   <td>{{order.currency_code}} {{product.price}}</td>
   <td id="arrow"><a>Write A Review</a></td>
 </tr>
```

In the controller,

```
var review;
$scope.parseProductId = function(id){
  review = $firebase((new Firebase('https://...')).child('product_reviews/' + id)).$asArray();
}
```

I have another add func in controller, when user click add button in the view html, add() will be called and saved the data to the firebase.

```
$scope.add = function (id, name, index) {
  $scope.product_id = id;
  $scope.product_name = name;
  $scope.$broadcast('show-errors-reset');

  var save = review.$add({
    reviewTitle: $scope.reviewTitle,
    review: $scope.review,
    rating_quality: $scope.rating,
    rating_pricing: $scope.rating1
  });
```

But ,This error is shown, 
**TypeError: Cannot read property '$add' of undefined**

Comment: You wrote it yourself - `Cannot read property '$add' of undefined`. At what point in the code is the property `$add` trying to be accessed on an object?

Comment: I want to save data from user to the firebase, so i used $add to be able to save data to the firebase .
but the firebase link will be directed according to the product_id from the user.

Comment: You declare `review` inside of a method, and it is not defined, which means you haven't called `parseProductId` before running `$scope.add()`. We couldn't guess the exact details based on the interesting way you've clipped your examples here to provide as brief of a picture (instead of complete) as possible into the code.

Answer (score 1):

Trying accessing review through the scope, it doesn't seem to be defined without the scope:

```
var save = $scope.review.$add({
```

Comment: can't also use $value, showing same error undefined

Comment: Sorry what? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: In the parseProductId function, i also declared other vars eg. var obj1 , var obj2. The values of those variables are accessed from the firebase.

Comment: And then, I wrote $scope.total_count = obj1.$value + obj2.$value + obj3.$value + obj4.$value + obj5.$value; in the add function.

Comment: This $value can't be used, also got undefined .

Comment: @spider show this in your question and code. You really, really, really need to read this before you continue:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve